# Is there a way to use Boolean for @PreviewParametr and use it for StateFlow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to "preview" a compose UI where I would like to have 2 different states previewed for `isVerifyBtnEnabledState` in order to make it I use `@PreviewParameter` this way:

```
    @Preview(
        name = "EN-Phone-portrait",
        locale = "en",
        device = Devices.PHONE,
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Preview(
        name = "EN-Tablet-landscape",
        locale = "en",
        device = Devices.TABLET,
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Preview(
        name = "EN-Tablet-portrait",
        locale = "en",
        device = "spec:id=reference_phone,shape=Normal,width=800,height=1280,unit=dp,dpi=420",
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Composable
    private fun PhonePreviewVerificationCodeScreen(
        @PreviewParameter(VerifyBtnEnabledStateProvider::class) verifyBtnEnabledState: Boolean
    ) {
        val userEmailState: StateFlow<String> = remember { MutableStateFlow("TEST") }
        val isVerifyBtnEnabledState: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = remember { MutableStateFlow(value = verifyBtnEnabledState) }
        val isUserVerificationCodeErrorState: StateFlow<Boolean> = remember { MutableStateFlow(value = false) }

        DrawVerificationCodeScreen(
            userEmailState = userEmailState,
            isVerifyBtnEnabledState = isVerifyBtnEnabledState,
            isUserVerificationCodeErrorState = isUserVerificationCodeErrorState
        ) { /* nothing */ }
    }

    class VerifyBtnEnabledStateProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<Boolean> {
        override val values: Sequence<Boolean> = sequenceOf(true, false)
    }
```

so here I have `VerifyBtnEnabledStateProvider` which is supposed to provide `true and false` values and I would expect to see different preiviews for both of them, instead it shows like `Render issue` with an error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myclasspath at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass  at java.lang.Class.forName0  at java.lang.Class.forName  at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposable

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can't reproduce, `@PreviewParameter` part seems to be correct. Android Studio 2023.1.1 Patch 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out that the problem was in that my PreviewProvider implementation was included as a nested class to the main one like:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
...
    @Preview(
        name = "EN-Phone-portrait",
        locale = "en",
        device = Devices.PHONE,
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Preview(
        name = "EN-Tablet-landscape",
        locale = "en",
        device = Devices.TABLET,
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Preview(
        name = "EN-Tablet-portrait",
        locale = "en",
        device = "spec:id=reference_phone,shape=Normal,width=800,height=1280,unit=dp,dpi=420",
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Composable
    private fun PhonePreviewVerificationCodeScreen(
        @PreviewParameter(VerifyBtnEnabledStateProvider::class) verifyBtnEnabledState: Boolean
    ) {
        val userEmailState: StateFlow<String> = remember { MutableStateFlow("TEST") }
        val isVerifyBtnEnabledState: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = remember { MutableStateFlow(value = verifyBtnEnabledState) }
        val isUserVerificationCodeErrorState: StateFlow<Boolean> = remember { MutableStateFlow(value = false) }

        DrawVerificationCodeScreen(
            userEmailState = userEmailState,
            isVerifyBtnEnabledState = isVerifyBtnEnabledState,
            isUserVerificationCodeErrorState = isUserVerificationCodeErrorState
        ) { /* nothing */ }
    }

    class VerifyBtnEnabledStateProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<Boolean> {
        override val values: Sequence<Boolean> = sequenceOf(true, false)
    }
...
}
```

After I pulled it out of the scope everything started to work as expected:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
...
    @Preview(
        name = "EN-Phone-portrait",
        locale = "en",
        device = Devices.PHONE,
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Preview(
        name = "EN-Tablet-landscape",
        locale = "en",
        device = Devices.TABLET,
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Preview(
        name = "EN-Tablet-portrait",
        locale = "en",
        device = "spec:id=reference_phone,shape=Normal,width=800,height=1280,unit=dp,dpi=420",
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Composable
    private fun PhonePreviewVerificationCodeScreen(
        @PreviewParameter(VerifyBtnEnabledStateProvider::class) verifyBtnEnabledState: Boolean
    ) {
        val userEmailState: StateFlow<String> = remember { MutableStateFlow("TEST") }
        val isVerifyBtnEnabledState: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = remember { MutableStateFlow(value = verifyBtnEnabledState) }
        val isUserVerificationCodeErrorState: StateFlow<Boolean> = remember { MutableStateFlow(value = false) }

        DrawVerificationCodeScreen(
            userEmailState = userEmailState,
            isVerifyBtnEnabledState = isVerifyBtnEnabledState,
            isUserVerificationCodeErrorState = isUserVerificationCodeErrorState
        ) { /* nothing */ }
    }
...
}

// PULLED IT OUT OF THE FRAGMENT CLASS SCOPE
    private class VerifyBtnEnabledStateProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<Boolean> {
        override val values: Sequence<Boolean> = sequenceOf(true, false)
    }
```

Honestly I don't know why it makes a difference, but now it works as expected.